# Error: status[x] is undefined

Tags: javascript

I want to create a dictionary that can be accessed like `status[a][b]`
where `a` and `b` are random strings that are not known at the time of initialization.

Here's the exact use case:

```
status = {}
name = {};
time = {};
score = {};
for (i=0; i<$scope.submissions.length; i++)
{
    e = $scope.submissions[i];
    status[e.rno] = status[e.rno] || {};
    time[e.rno] = time[e.rno] || 0;
    score[e.rno] = score[e.rno] || 0;
    status[e.rno][e.problem] = status[e.rno][e.problem] || 0;
    if (e.score == 100 && status[e.rno][e.problem] == 0)
    {
        status[e.rno][e.problem] = 100;
        time[e.rno] += e.id;
        score[e.rno] += 100;
    }
}
console.log(score["20161230"]);
```

It throws the error: `Error: status[e.rno] is undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`status` is a window property and you cannot change its type. So you should use `var` if you are in a function scope (*to avoid using the global window property*) or use another name if it has to be global.

Comment: @anukul Just get in the habit of always using local variables, unless you really need a global variable.